# Numerical Solution for ODE with a squared term inhibiting use of Euler's Method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, eulers-method

I have this ODE:

$$A(x)\ddot{x}+B(x)\dot{x}^2+C(x) = 0$$

$A,B,C$ are functions of $x(t)$. Usually I'd solve this numerically using Euler's method but in this case the $\dot{x}^2$ is giving me problems since I cannot solve the equation for $x(t+\delta)$ because I have both $x(t+\delta)$ and $x(t+\delta)^2$.

What does one do in this case? I am open to using other numerical methods as well...

Answer (score 1):

You should not use any Euler method to solve anything serious.

If you want to apply any Runge-Kutta or one-step method, you need to transform the ODE into a first order system
\begin{align}
\dot x &= v\\
\dot v &= -\frac{B(x)v^2+C(x)}{A(x)}
\end{align}
To this first order system you can now apply any Runge-Kutta method, not only the highly inefficient Euler method.

Comment: Thanks. Just to clarify, one thing. What I should do next is first solve for the velocity and then using the velocity, solve for the position, right?

Comment: No, you solve simultaneously as a vector valued system $\dot y=F(t,y)$ with $y=\begin{bmatrix}x\\v\end{bmatrix}$. Using $y_{k+1}=y_k+h·F(t_k,y_k)$ for the Euler method.